# Reporting - easy to build interface linked to a postgres database

Tags: self-hosted, reporting, user-interface, postgresql

I'm looking for a tool that can create reports but also interface that can manipulate data.

These reports and interfaces will be deployed on Windows PCs.
Access and Excel spreadsheets are excluded. The reports and interfaces will be linked to a postgres database.

I'm looking for something robust, possibly web based but this is not mandatory.

I want to build an interface where I can write / insert / update datas from a database, I found [Metabase](http://www.metabase.com/start/other.html) but I think it may no be able to create interfaces to manipulate the data.

Any suggestions are more than welcomed as I'm trying to steer away from access and excel.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to interpret your question, you mention self-hosted (in a tag) and also web-based, so I'm actually going to suggest a couple of SaaS solutions - one with a self-hosted option:

1. **Tableau** - a powerful, enterprise-class data reporting and visualzation tool http://www.tableau.com/products
2. **QueryTree** - a more entry-level data reporting tool that does support PostGreSQL databases
   http://querytreeapp.com/features/

Both products feature a free trial period, QueryTree is more aimed at SME / startups (I work on QueryTree) while Tableau looks to be more 'enterprise-ready' and I think also offers a self-hosted version.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to give [DBxtra](http://dbxtra.com/) a try, it connects to Postgres directly, it's self hosted, and can be accessed from any computer with just a web browser, also, it's easy to use and have interactivity options (Dashboards) as well as pixel perfect reports.

P.S.: I'm a DBxtra evangelist.